# Spring Data JPA: using object retrieved with `JpaRepository.getOne(id)`

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jhipster

In my Spring Boot application generated with JHipster (v6.0.1)  Kotlin blueprint (v0.8.0) I have the following POST request handler

```
    @PostMapping("/book")
    fun createBook(@RequestBody createBookVM: CreateBookVM): ResponseEntity<Book> {
        val author = authorRepository.getOne(createBookVM.authorId)
        val userLogin = SecurityUtils.getCurrentUserLogin().orElseThrow { RuntimeException("User not logged in") }
        val user = userRepository.findOneByLogin(userLogin).orElseThrow { RuntimeException("IMPOSSIBLE: user does not exist in DB") }
        val book= Book()
        book.author = author // FIXME
        book.user = user
        log.debug("Author object with id : {}", author.id) // THIS WORKS
        val result = bookRepository.save(book)
        return ResponseEntity.created(URI("/api/books/" + result.id))
            .headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityCreationAlert(applicationName, true, ENTITY_NAME, result.id.toString()))
            .body(result)
    }
```

The problem is that the `author` is not added to the `book` (`book.author` will be `null`). However, I can access the values of `author` as shown with the logging statement. Adding `user` to `book` also works fine.

I suppose the problem is that `authorRepository.getOne(createBookVM.authorId)` returns a proxy object, not an instance of `Author`, but I do not know how to cope with this situation.

Comment: What is the relation betweek `Book` and `Author`? Please show the code

Comment: Does it work if you extract the business logic to a service method, and make that method `@Transactional`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `authorRepository.getOne(createBookVM.binId)` use `authorRepository.findById(createBookVM.binId)`.

`T getOne(ID id)` returns a reference, not an entity.

```
/**
 * Returns a reference to the entity with the given identifier.
 *
 * @param id must not be {@literal null}.
 * @return a reference to the entity with the given identifier.
 * @see EntityManager#getReference(Class, Object)
 * @throws javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException if no entity exists for given {@code id}.
 */
T getOne(ID id);
```

`Optional<T> findById(ID id)` returns an entity.

```
/**
 * Retrieves an entity by its id.
 *
 * @param id must not be {@literal null}.
 * @return the entity with the given id or {@literal Optional#empty()} if none found
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if {@code id} is {@literal null}.
 */
Optional<T> findById(ID id);
```

Also you can use `authorRepository.findOne(createBookVM.binId)` for older versions than jpa 2.x.x :

```
/**
 * Retrieves an entity by its id.
 * 
 * @param id must not be {@literal null}.
 * @return the entity with the given id or {@literal null} if none found
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if {@code id} is {@literal null}
 */
T findOne(ID id);
```

Comment: Given the OP wants to reference an existing `Author` in a `Book`, `getOne` is in fact *the right tool* for the job

Comment: He wants the same behavior that `user` has, and in `user` returns an entity, not a reference, and it's correctly assigned to `book`.

Comment: The problem is that `getOne` should work in this case. The fact that it does not means there is another issue with the code. What you're suggesting is merely a workaround *and* a bad practice

Comment: Can you justify me because it's bad practice?

Comment: It's bad practice to load the entire state of the entity (`findById`) from the db when all you need to link it with another entity is its `id` (`getOne`)